# NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver

Is the parameter for NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: supposed to be the array I am trying to save, or the array converted into NSData?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To convert a generic array to an `NSData`, you need an archiver! If you know how to feed the `NSData`, you know how to use `NSKeyedArchiver`. So:

```
NSArray* array= ... ;
NSData* data=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
```

Of course all elements in your `array` needs to implement `encodeWithCoder:`.

Comment: For completeness, you use an NSKeyedUnarchiver to do the reverse.

Comment: "all elements in your array needs to implement encodeWithCoder:" <-- this is only needed for custom objects?

Comment: all elements in your array need to have an implementation of `encodeWithCoder:`, either by Apple or by you. You can check if an Apple-supplied object implements it or not by having a look at the official documentation... see if it implements the protocol `NSCoder`.

Answer (score 16):

Yuji's answer is right. but more accurately, your element of an array have to implement protocol  and fillin your own code to methods initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder:
like:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
        self.author = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"author"];
        self.published = [decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"published"];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"time"];
    [encoder encodeObject:author forKey:@"author"];
    [encoder encodeBool:published forKey:@"published"];
}
```

then you can use the archiver and unchariver like:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:notes];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"notes"];

NSData *notesData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notes"];
NSArray *notes = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:notesData];
```

For more, you can get reference "[Archiving Objective-C Objects with NSCoding](http://soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding)".