# How to get exact data from NSUserDefaults in Objective C,iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsindexpath

I have NSMutableArray and I am trying to save that array in NSUserDefaults.Here is my code :

to save :

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[currentDefaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:userSession.transactionArray] forKey:@"TransId"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

to retrieve :

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefault objectForKey:@"TransId"];
NSMutableArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
userSession.transactionArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:oldSavedArray];
```

But, I am getting my array in log,

```
"<NSIndexPath: 0x160f8640> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x1602bd70> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x16026900> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0x14f01dd0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}"
```

How to get actual data from this.Can anybody help me to get this value properly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in here except your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save NSMutableArrays in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803288/how-to-save-nsmutablearrays-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Each and every object in your array has to conform to <NSCoding> protocol in order for array to be saved/retrieved correctly.

Comment: you should ask about displaying the nsdata objects

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSArray *aviArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:aviArray forKey:@"Arraykey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

 NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Arraykey"] objectAtIndex:0]); 

 NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Arraykey"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to: [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745842/nskeyedarchiver-archiveddatawithrootobject)

You're missing the implementations of initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder:. One of the answers describes how to write those.